# Disappearing strings

Tags: c, string, malloc, strdup

This is my first post here so I thank everyone in advance for any and all help.

I'm having an issue with disappearing information. The program is supposed to read in book titles and library ID numbers from a file, create a hash table of linked lists where each node contains a book struct that holds the title of the book and another linked list with the library IDs where the book can be found. At this point I am just trying to fill the hash table but for some reason my title values are disappearing. The file format is shown below:

2345, Old Man and the Sea
567434, Harry Potter
1233, The Art of Learning
etc...

I have

```
typedef NodeStruct {void* data; NodePtr prev; NodePtr next;} NodeStruct;

typedef NodeStruct* NodePtr;

typedef ListStruct {NodePtr first; NodePtr last; NodePtr current; } ListStruct;

typedef ListStruct* ListHndl;

typedef BookStruct {char* title; ListHndl lib; } BookStruct;

typedef BookStruct* BookHndl;

FILE *fileptr;
int numlines;
int numslots;
int i;
int index;
NodePtr fillnode;


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    fileptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if (!fileptr) {
        printf("Error: cannot open file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int *libID = malloc(sizeof(int));
    printf("(main) libID: %p\n", libID);
    fscanf(fileptr, "%d %d", &numlines, &numslots);
    printf("(main) numlines: %d   numslots: %d\n", numlines, numslots);
    ListHndl *H = calloc(numslots, sizeof(ListHndl));
    printf("(main) calloc iterated\n");

    for (i = 0; i < numlines; i++) {
        printf("*************LOOP #%d*************\n", i);
        char *title = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
        if (fscanf(fileptr, "%d%*c%*c%[^\n]", libID, title) == 0) {
            printf("Error: incorrect # of keys\n");
            return 1;
        }
        printf("(main) book: %s  ID: %d\n", title, *libID); 
        index = hash(title, numslots);
        printf("(main) index: %d\n", index);
        printf("(main) hash[index]: %p\n", H[index]);
        if (H[index] == NULL) {
            H[index] = newList();
            printf("(main_if_H_NULL) hash[index]: %p\n", H[index]);
            BookHndl B = newBook(title, libID);
            printf("(main_if_H_NULL) BookHndl B: %p\n", B);
            insertAtFront(H[index],(void *) B);
            printf("(main_if_H_NULL) H[index] title: %s  ID: %d\n", ((BookHndl) H[index]->first->data)->title, 
                        *((int *) ((BookHndl) H[index]->first->data)->lib->first->data));
        }
        printAll(H, numslots);
        NodePtr S = searchTitle(H[index], title);
        printf("(main) NodePtr S: %p\n", S);
        if (S == NULL) {
            BookHndl B = newBook(title, libID);
            insertAtBack(H[index], (void *) B);
            printf("(main_if_!S) inserted book\n");
        } else {
            printf("(main_if_S)\n");
            ListHndl idL = ((BookHndl) S->data)->lib;
            if (searchID(idL, libID) == 0) {
                insertAtBack(idL, (void *) libID);
                printf("(main_if_S) inserted libID\n");
            }
        }
        free((char *) title);
        free((NodePtr) S);
        printAll(H, numslots);
        printf("hash[%d]: %s in library # %d\n", index, title, *libID);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

there are actually four fscanf arguments %d for libID, %*c to jump over ",", another %*c to jump over the " ", and %[^/n] to read the title until a newline is read. The print statement shortly after confirms correct values in both libID and title. At printAll(H, numslots), all values are present, upon return of NodePtr S = searchTitle(H[index], title) the title is gone. Below are my newBook and searchTitle functions

```
BookHndl newBook(char* str, int* ID) {
    BookHndl B = malloc(sizeof(BookStruct));
    /*B->title = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);*/
    B->title = strdup(str);
    printf("(newBook) B->title = %s\n", B->title);
    B->lib = newList();
    printf("(newBook) B->lib = %p\n", B->lib);
    insertAtFront(B->lib, (void *) ID);
    printf("(newBook) B->lib->first = %d\n", *((int *)B->lib->first->data));

    return B;
}

NodePtr searchTitle(ListHndl L, char* key) {
    assert(L != NULL);
    if (isEmpty(L)) {
        printf("Book list empty\n");
        return NULL;
    } else {
        L->current = L->first;
        printf("(searchTitle) ListHndl L = %p, L->first = %p, L->first->data = %p\n", L, L->first, (BookHndl) L->first->data);
        while (L->current != NULL) {
            BookHndl B = malloc(sizeof(BookStruct));
            B = (BookHndl) L->current->data;
            printf("(searchTitle) bookhandle B = %p\n", B);
            printf("(searchTitle) B->title = %s\n B->ID = %d\n", B->title, *((int *) B->lib->first->data));
            if (strcmp(B->title, key) == 0) {
                free(B);
                return L->current;
            }
            free(B);
            L->current = L->current->next;
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: reduce the number of english words... and shows us the code - this looks like a memory leak or some local variable gets destroyed...

Comment: `fscanf(fileptr, "%d%*c%*c%[^\n]", libID, name)` I count three '%' signs and two arguments. And there is a semicolon missing. BTW what is LibID? There is no definition for it. Finally: typedef considered harmful...

Comment: Also, check return value of scanf functions to detect parse errors.

Comment: I made some edits and added much more of my code. I feel I am missing some easy, fundamental truth about pointers here, can anyone spot it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is broken.

```
BookHndl B = malloc(sizeof(BookStruct));
B = (BookHndl) L->current->data;
// ...
free(B);
```

This will leak a chunk of memory and then free something out of your node structure. Fix this, and the problem might go away.

Comment: Did the OP change the question after your answer?

Comment: That was it! I had it in a few places, too. Thank you @david.pfx